# Esconder div si no tiene clases multiples

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo un conjunto de `div` que puedo mostrar u ocultar mediante el uso de `checkboxes`. Estoy usando jQuery para encontrar los `div` con una cierta clase de CSS, y sólo mostrar ellos.

El html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="inputs">
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="azul" />Azul
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="verde" />Verde
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="rojo" />Rojo
</div>
<br>
<div class="tags azul">Azul</div>
<div class="tags verde azul">Verde y Azul</div>
<div class="tags verde rojo">Verde y Rojo</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$('input').click(function() {
  $('.tags').hide();
  $('input:checked').each(function(i) {
    $('div.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

El problema que tengo es que si selecciono tanto el azul y el verde, en lugar de sólo de un `div`, muestra los tres, ya que todos los `div` tienen la clase CSS azul o verde.

Lo que quiero hacer es editar el código para que cuando selecciono más de un `checkbox` solo muestra los `div` que tienen ambas clases CSS.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CalvT/0cv52xa6/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizando [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) y [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) puedes resolver el problema fácilmente.

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  $('.tags').hide();
  var marcados = $('input:checked').map(function() { 
     return $( this ).val();
  }).get();
  $('div.' + marcados.join('.')).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="azul" />Azul
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="verde" />Verde
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" value="rojo" />Rojo
</div>
<br>
<div class="tags azul">Azul</div>
<div class="tags verde azul">Verde y Azul</div>
<div class="tags verde rojo">Verde y Rojo</div>
```

Explicación:

- `$('input:checked').map` crea un array en base al valor retornado en la funcion, en el caso que planteas, como usamos `$( this ).val()`, retorna `['azul','verde']`.
- `marcados.join('.')` construye una cadena, separadas por puntos con los elementos de `marcados`, mismo caso  se reduce a `azul.verde`.
- luego, se muestra lo que contenga ambas clases: `$('div.azul.verde').show();`